# How to prevent Google Chrome suggestion on input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker

[image]

```
<div class="customDiv">
    <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-sm-5 my-1">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text">From</div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="customFrom" class="form-control" id="customFrom" placeholder="08-21-2019">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-5 my-1">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text">To</div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" name="customTo" class="form-control" id="customTo" placeholder="08-21-2019">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 my-1">
            <button id="apply" class="btn btn-success btn-sm ">Apply</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

How do I prevent the Google suggestion ?

Comment: Try setting `autocomplete="false"`?

Comment: `autocomplete="off"` added to the `input` should do the trick.

Comment: I remembered trying those. But I’ll attempt again right now. I’ll share result.

Comment: You can add yourself to chromes bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=914451

Comment: `autocomplete="false"` +  `autocomplete="off"` - not working

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `autocomplete="off"` in the form or the input.

For example

```
<form method="post" action="/form" autocomplete="off">
[…]
</form>
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

However some browsers, and user extensions might not respect that. Another trick can be renaming your input to something that the browser might not recognize, that way it will stop the suggestion.

Comment: not working ... autocomplete="off" or autocomplete="false"

Comment: Yep @kyo I mentioned in the answer, some times it doesn't work :shrug:

Comment: It works only on old versions of Chrome